# Get attribute string value from html

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am building a macro to extract data from website using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba). Currently I can easily get value from table content using element syntax like `obj.getElementsByTagName("td").innerText`. However, when there are some non-innerText data in some cells, I am getting trouble. It's like this:

```
<img src="/images/amber_pending.gif" border="0" alt="Pending" title="Pending">
```

I attempted to extract the attribute value from "title" using syntax I found from others:

```
For Each tbObj In doc.getElementsByClassName("report removeTdBorder")
    i = 1
    For Each trObj In tbObj.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        If i >= 3 Then
            j = 1
            For Each tdObj In trObj.getElementsByTagName("td")
                If j = 1 Then
                    Set imgObj = tdObj.getElementsByTagName("img")
                    dataArray(i, j) = imgObj.getAttribute("title")
                    Debug.Print imgObj.getAttribute("title")
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, j) = dataArray(i, j)
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, j).WrapText = False
                Else
                    dataArray(i, j) = tdObj.innerText
                    Debug.Print i & ", " & j & ": " & dataArray(i, j)
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, j) = dataArray(i, j)
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, j).WrapText = False
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Next tdObj
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next trObj
Next tbObj
```

But this code goes error every time and it said "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method" at the line `dataArray(i, j) = imgObj.getAttribute("title")`. Could some one help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Set imgObj = tdObj.getElementsByTagName("img")
```

returns a collection of images (even if there's only one to be found), so you can address a specific image using (eg):

```
dataArray(i, j) = imgObj(0).getAttribute("title")
```

Comment: thanks for helping. however, it seems this one not working as well. it said "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" for dataArray(i, j) = imgObj(1).getAttribute("title"). is there any other reason?

Comment: I think that IXMLDOMNodeList is zero-based so `imgObj(0).getAttribute("title")` should work

Comment: Thanks @barrowc!! this works!! and thanks @Tim Williams for your awesome solution as well!